# Не видно содержимого вкладок TabLayout и ViewPager внутри NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Использую `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` внутри `NestedScrollView`.
В результате видны только заголовки вкладок, а содержимое не видно. 
Моя разметка:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Any controls -->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Если `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` вынести за пределы `NestedScrollView`, то всё отображается нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашёл [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/346364).

Оказывается если `ViewPager` находится в `ScrollView`, он должен иметь фиксированную высоту. Если же `ViewPager` находится в другом `layout` файле, то устанавливать статическую высоту надо не `ViewPager`, а через который он подключается.